# Ignore Empty Cells

Tags: google-apps-script

I wonder if someone could help me.

I have set up the script coding below to generate a Google Doc Template based on data in a Google Sheet.
The issue I'm having is that when I run the AutoFill Docs process within google sheets, it's creating the letter and adding spaces in the letter for any cells that are empty.

So for example, I have 4 headings (Address 1, Address 2, Address 3 and Address 4) based on the customer's details not all of these are filled.

When the letter/ google doc is generated, it's putting spaces in for the empty cells (See below)

Bob  Smith
32 Bob Road

Bobbington

B23 4YH

for empty cells, I need it to ignore these and generate the letter as below:

Bob  Smith
32 Bob Road
Bobbington
B23 4YH

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
  
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {

  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1oa-BtAhFKsvJ37Dl26Xvt2QTe9HjSz8vE9YVhtXjPA8');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1kPVjBvCrdtb6k3bafl-g-s64b40-oH6I')
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Daysavers')
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
  if (index === 0) return;
  if (row[10]) return;

  const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[2]} Customer Details` , destinationFolder)
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
  const body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText('{{Case Reference}}', row[0]);
  body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', row[1]);
  body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', row[2]);
  body.replaceText('{{Address 1}}', row[3]);
  body.replaceText('{{Address 2}}', row[4]);
  body.replaceText('{{Address 3}}', row[5]);
  body.replaceText('{{Address 4}}', row[6]);
  body.replaceText('{{Postcode}}', row[7]);
  body.replaceText('{{First Name 2}}', row[8]);
  body.replaceText('{{Number}}', row[9]);

  doc.saveAndClose();
  const url = doc.getUrl();
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 11).setValue(url)

  })

}
```

Comment: Are you able to share a copy of the Google Doc template in question?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not the script putting space, but just the space between the address items leaving there.

```js
body.replaceText(' {{Address 2}}', row[4] ? ' ' + row[4] : '');
```

Do this with 3 and 4 also

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I'm afraid it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

If the row of the spreadsheet always holds the data you want to insert, in the correct order, you could avoid the multiple placeholders in your template and just put a single placeholder, then replace all of your `body.replaceText(...)` lines with a single line:

```
body.replaceText('{{Single Placeholder}}', row.filter(Boolean).join(' '));
```

[`row.filter(Boolean)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) produces an array with only the cell values that have non-empty strings or non-zero number values, and [`.join(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) joins them all into one space-separated string.

If you still get the line breaks, it's possible there are newline characters in your spreadsheet cells.  Eliminate them with [`.replace(/\n/g,'')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
body.replaceText('{{Single Placeholder}}', row.filter(Boolean).join(' ').replace(/\n/g,'');
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your suggestion. Can you confirm what you mean by Single Placeholder? What do I replace '{{Single Placeholder}}' for? Sorry I'm a novice when it comes to this!

Comment: @ChrisEastup I'm making assumptions about the content of the Google Doc you're using for a template, but I'm guessing part of its body looks like "{{First Name}} {{Last Name}} {{Address 1}} {{Address 2}} ... {{Postcode}}".  I'm suggesting you replace all of that content with just the text "{{Single Placeholder}}".  Then in your script, replace all of the lines that start with `body.replaceText` with the one single line I've suggested above.  Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Ok I see, sorry, yeah I’ve tried that doesn’t work. So yeah the letter has Address 1 etc which makes up a customers address depending on what info is put into the Google sheet, so I’ve managed to get the code working so it takes out the Address 2 for instance if nothing is entered into that corresponding cell on the spreadsheet but the doc still has a space where that entry should have been.

Comment: @ChrisEastup Then it's probably something to do with the specifics of your Google Doc or the data in your spreadsheet.  Are you able to share them as view only and paste the links here?